# Vlookup() equivalent in Dplyr

Tags: r, join, dplyr, tidyverse

My df looks like:

```
library(tidyverse) 
df_1 <- tibble::tribble(
          ~sub_date, ~value_1, ~value_2,
          "2020-05",       58,      130,
          "2020-05",       58,       "check",
          "2020-03",       50,      120,
          "2020-03",       55,       "check",
          "2020-03",       55,       "check"
          )
```

I want to change the values of the rows containing "check" with the reference values here:

```
df_ref <- tibble::tribble(
            ~sub_date, ~ref_value,
            "2020-05",        123,
            "2020-03",        234
            )
```

Basically - using the `df_ref` table as a reference only for the rows containing check.

I want to use the equivalent of a lookup() in excel, used in a if() function.

Final result being:

```
df_final <- tibble::tribble(
              ~sub_date, ~value_1, ~value_2,
              "2020-05",       58,      130,
              "2020-05",       58,      123,
              "2020-03",       50,      120,
              "2020-03",       55,      234,
              "2020-03",       55,      234
              )
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do a join. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html

Comment: I understand it's join, but only  for a subset of rows, not the whole dataframe @cory. I don't understand how to do it when it applies to rows with a specific string

Comment: Yeah, vlookup is actually a really bad implementation of a join, if you want to see the exact wrong results, you need to them filter somehow just the top results

Comment: Alright, you got this. Split it into two parts... the join to create a new column, then an ifelse sub it into your column.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
df_1 %>% 
  mutate(value_2 = as.numeric(na_if(value_2, "check"))) %>% 
  left_join(df_ref, by = "sub_date") %>% 
  mutate(value_2 = coalesce(value_2, ref_value)) %>% 
  select(-ref_value)
```

Small explanation: first we set to `NA` all the `"check"` values thanks to `na_if`, then we join with the lookup table, then we `coalesce` the two columns `value_2` and `ref_value`, i.e. take the first non-missing value between the two.

---

Output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   sub_date value_1 value_2
#   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 2020-05       58     130
# 2 2020-05       58     123
# 3 2020-03       50     120
# 4 2020-03       55     234
# 5 2020-03       55     234
```

---

Small note: your `df_1` doesn't work as you pasted it in your question. Below I adjusted its values as character so that it works

```
df_1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sub_date, ~value_1, ~value_2,
  "2020-05",       58,      "130",
  "2020-05",       58,      "check",
  "2020-03",       50,      "120",
  "2020-03",       55,      "check",
  "2020-03",       55,      "check"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do it a single line with `ifelse` and `match` since we aren't really interested in joining the dataframes. Wrap it in `as.numeric` if you want numeric output.

```r
library(dplyr)

mutate(df_1, 
       value_2 = ifelse(value_2 == "check", 
                        df_ref$ref_value[match(sub_date, df_ref$sub_date)],
                        value_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good luck when there are multiple matches

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sub_date, ~value_1, ~value_2,
  "2020-05",       58,      "130",
  "2020-05",       58,       "check",
  "2020-03",       50,      "120",
  "2020-03",       55,       "check",
  "2020-03",       55,       "check"
)

df_ref <- tibble::tribble(
  ~sub_date, ~ref_value,
  "2020-05",        123,
  "2020-03",        234
)

df_1 %>% 
  left_join(df_ref) %>%
  mutate(value_2_true = ifelse(value_2 == "check",ref_value,value_2)) %>%
  mutate(value_2 = value_2_true %>% as.numeric()) %>% 
  select(-value_2_true,-ref_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
ref_lut <- with(df_ref, setNames(ref_value, sub_date))

df_1$value_2 <- 
  ifelse(df_1$value_2 == "check", ref_lut[df_1$sub_date], df_1$value_2)

df_1

  sub_date value_1 value_2
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>  
1 2020-05       58 130    
2 2020-05       58 123    
3 2020-03       50 120    
4 2020-03       55 234    
5 2020-03       55 234
```